# Snap, Crackle, Pop: Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just started learning front development and have run into a snag in one of my projects.
The project wants me to create a function: SnapScrackle with a parameter: maxValue and create a loop from
1 to the maxValue with concatenated text string as a console.log result.

here is my code:

```
function snapCrackle(maxValue) {
    let text = ""
    let index
for ( index = 1; index <= maxValue; index ++ ) {
    if (maxValue % 2 !== 0) {
        text += "Snap, " }
     if (maxValue % 5 === 0) {
        text+= "Crackle, " } 
     if ((maxValue % 2 !== 0)&&(maxValue % 5 === 0)){
        text += "SnapCrackle, "} 
    if ((maxValue % 2 === 0) || (maxValue % 5 !== 0)){
        text += (maxValue + ",")
    } 
}
console.log(text)
}
snapCrackle()
```

*when I run the code I get a duplication of whatever maxValue I input
examples: [14] gives 14,(x14) [2] gives 2,(x2)

- I get the correct text and values, but it doesn't count up to MaxValue, it only outputs multiples of
  the answer corresponding to it.

what would you recommend to concatenate text strings running from 1-maxValue?

Comment: use if/elseif/else, then populate an array then join, instead of concating

Comment: You don't pass the argument here: `snapCrackle()`.

Comment: please add an example of max value 15.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some parts:

- Replace `index` (actually there is no array to work with) with `value` and use this inside the loop instead of `maxValue`, because `value` is the only value which is changing.
- Take the most complex check as first condition.
- Take [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) to continue the loop if a condition is `true` and the text was changing.
- Add at last the value itselft, if all other conditions are false.
- At last call the function with a value for `maxValue`.

```js
function snapCrackle(maxValue) {
    let text = "";
    for (let value = 1; value <= maxValue; value++) {
        if (value % 2 !== 0 && value % 5 === 0) {
            text += "SnapCrackle, ";
            continue;
        }
        if (value % 2 !== 0) {
            text += "Snap, ";
            continue;
        }
        if (value % 5 === 0) {
            text += "Crackle, ";
            continue;
        }
        text += value + ", ";
    }
    console.log(text);
}

snapCrackle(15);
```